# Diagonalization of Hamiltonian involving two particle interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, second-quantization

For a non-interacting Hamiltonian, $H = \sum_{\alpha\beta} H_{\alpha\beta} c_\alpha^\dagger c_\beta$, we can diagonalize the $H_{\alpha\beta}$ matrix to find the eigenstates, which allows us to write the Hamiltonian in diagonal form, $H = \sum_n \epsilon_n \phi_n^\dagger \phi_n$, where $\{\phi_n\}$ and $\{c_\beta\}$ are fermionic operators related by a unitary transformation.

For another kind of Hamiltonian involving two-particle interactions, $H = \sum_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} H_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} c_\alpha^\dagger c_\beta^\dagger c_\gamma c_\delta$, I am wondering if, analogously, it would be possible to find a suitable basis and write the matrix in the form $H = \sum_{mn} (\epsilon_{mn} \phi_m^\dagger \phi_m \phi_n^\dagger \phi_n + v_{mn} \phi_m^\dagger \phi_n)$? (I'm trying to allow for more possibilities with the second term.)

As a positive example, consider the Hamiltonian $H = c^\dagger_1 c^\dagger_2 c_3 c_1 + c^\dagger_1 c^\dagger_3 c_2 c_1$. Define the transformation
$$
\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\ \phi_3 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

so that
\begin{align*}
H &= c^\dagger_1 c^\dagger_2 c_3 c_1 + c^\dagger_1 c^\dagger_3 c_2 c_1 \\
&= c^\dagger_1 c_1 (c^\dagger_2 c_3 + c^\dagger_3 c_2) \\
&= \phi^\dagger_1 \phi_1 (\phi^\dagger_2 \phi_2 - \phi^\dagger_3 \phi_3) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Your terminology is strange.  The first Hamiltonian is not a one-particle Hamiltonian. It's a second-quantized Hamiltonian that can represent a system with *any* number of particles, but in which there are no *two-particle interactions*.  The second Hamiltonian is one for which there are two-particle interactions, but it still is a second-quantized Hamiltonian for a system with any number of particles.

Comment: @march thanks I have edited the question based on your feedback. Do let me know if there is anything still unclear.

Comment: @march The terminology is, as far as I can tell, however quite common. I.e. the second quantization of an operator on the single-particle Hilbert space is also called "one-body" or "one-particle" operator.